# SQLAlchemy / Flask / Google Cloud SQL -- How deals with UTF8MB4

Tags: python, mysql, google-cloud-platform, flask-sqlalchemy

This is my error :

```
pymysql.err.DataError: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xF0\\x9F\\x91\\x87' for column 'text' at row 1")
```

It's a smiley that I want to write in column. So initialy not manage by SQL. UTF8 vs UTF8MB4.

With the help of lot of topics there I try many things to change my parameters. This is what I've already set :

**#1**

My database is one Google Cloud SQL so I change parameters via this field :
[image]

**#2**

I try to manualy force via this command directly on the SQL terminal :

```
ALTER DATABASE my_database_name CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

**#3**

I add charset parameter at the end of the SQLALCHEMY URL :

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = '[URL]?charset=utf8mb4'
```

**#4**
I try to add this parameter to FLASK SQLACHEMY :

```
MYSQL_DATABASE_CHARSET = 'utf8mb4'
MYSQL_CHARSET = 'utf8mb4'
```

Didn't work, always the same error.

This is my configuration on SQL :

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%character%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+

mysql> show variables like "%collation%";
+----------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value              |
+----------------------+--------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci    |
| collation_database   | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8mb4_general_ci |
+----------------------+--------------------+

+-------+-------------+--------------------+
| Field | Type        | Collation          |
+-------+-------------+--------------------+
| text  | text        | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
```

Some fields still on utf8 like `character_set_client` or `character_set_connection`. Is it the problem ?

How change this values without acces to the `my.cnf` ?

Thanks in advance for your help ! !

**More informations**

This is the table's declaration :

```
@dataclass
class Post(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'post'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}

[...]

    text: str #dataclass
    text = db.Column(db.Text,unique=False,nullable=True)

[...]

    def __init__(self, id, social_media):
        self.id = id
        self.social_media = social_media
```

and the part of code :

```
data = {'id':'64145', 'message': 'some text... and the smiley : ', [OTHER_FIELDS]}

new_post = db.session.query(Post).filter(Post.id == data['id']).one_or_none() or Post(
    id = data['id'],
    social_media = 'social'
)

new_post.text = data.get('message') or None

db.session.add(new_post)
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: It is not possible to change that flags though the my.cnf file. If you want to change a flag you need to take a look at this https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags to see the supported flags. Nevertheless, that both blags are not supported. I would like to know what are you trying to do, from where you are trying to connect?  what is the code you are trying to use?

Comment: Hi ! My code is executed on Google App Engine. It's simple SQL request which is created by SQLAlchemy. Datas come froms the web, in this example it's comment scrap on social media. It's working well until a smiley appear. Please find the [Complete logs](https://pastebin.com/CE3buM4A) I'll add more information in my question. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Interesting fact**

I try to connect my flask app directly from my local computer to the SQL Cloud with the [proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy) and it's working !

The two urls :

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mysql+pymysql://robot:__password__@/__database_name__?unix_socket=/cloudsql/__google_app__:__region__:__google_database__?charset=utf8mb4"
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mysql+pymysql://robot:__password__@localhost/__database_name__?charset=utf8mb4"
```

OK. So I'm just dumb.

`SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mysql+pymysql://robot:__password__@/__database_name__?unix_socket=/cloudsql/__google_app__:__region__:__google_database__`**?**`charset=utf8mb4"`

Has to be :

`SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mysql+pymysql://robot:__password__@/__database_name__?unix_socket=/cloudsql/__google_app__:__region__:__google_database__`**&**`charset=utf8mb4"`